I'm trying to prevent users from adding Topic Tags to Salesforce Knowledge articles
I have users who will need access to Knowledge articles in Salesforce, but I want to prevent them from being able to add Topic Tags.  I'm not fully familiar with Knowledge, and most of the guides I've read don't seem to cover much about the tags (other than saying how useful they are).  I'm working on a legacy setup and some users aren't able to add tags (great) others can (boo) - I only want our admins to be able to do this.  I've added some screenshots below - can anyone please advise because it's driving me nuts.
Can add tags
Can't add tags
